# How do you save meta in select box in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I'm having trouble saving the data in the select box. Everything else saves just fine. I can select the option and save the post, but on refresh the select fields reset to the default value again while the other fields stay set. Suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
function category_list($tag, $taxonomy){
    $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);

    foreach($tax_terms as $term_single) {
        print('<'.$tag.' value="'.$term_single->name.'">'.$term_single->name.'</'.$tag.'>');
    }
}

function page_options_metabox_defaults() {
    return array(
        'city' => '',
        'office' => ''
        'location_full' => '',
        'location_2' => '',
        'location_4' = ''
    );
}

function page_options_metabox() {
    // Can only be used on a single post type (ie. page or post or a custom post type).
    // Must be repeated for each post type you want the metabox to appear on.
    add_meta_box(
        'page_options_metabox', // Metabox ID
        'Page Options', // Title to display
        'page_options_render_metabox', // Function to call that contains the metabox content
        'page', // Post type to display metabox on
        'normal', // Where to put it (normal = main colum, side = sidebar, etc.)
        'default' // Priority relative to other metaboxes
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'page_options_metabox' );


// This is the function  makes a meta box to specify dialog tech numbers`
function page_options_render_metabox() {

    // Variables
    global $post; // Get the current post data
    $saved = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'page_options', true ); // Get the saved values
    $defaults = page_options_metabox_defaults(); // Get the default values
    $details = wp_parse_args( $saved, $defaults ); // Merge the two in case any fields don't exist in the saved data
    ?>
        <fieldset>
            <!--the fields-->
            <h4>Locations</h4>
            <div>
            <!--city-->
            <label for="page_options_custom_metabox">
                    <?php _e( 'City', 'page_options' );?>
                </label>
                <select style="width:25%;"
                    type="text"
                    name="page_options_custom_metabox[city]"
                    id="page_options_custom_metabox_city">

                    <?php
                    category_list('option','location-city');
                    ?>

                    </select>
                    <br>

            <!--office-->
            <label for="page_options_custom_metabox">
                    <?php _e( 'Specific Office', 'page_options' );?>
                </label>
                <input
                    style="width:25%;"
                    type="text"
                    name="page_options_custom_metabox[office]"
                    id="page_options_custom_metabox_office"
                    value="<?php echo esc_attr( $details['office'] ); ?>"><br>
                <br>
                <br>

            <!--column count-->
            <strong><label  for="page_options_custom_metabox">
                    <?php _e( 'adjust columns', 'page_options' );?>
                </label></strong>
                <br>
                <!--full width-->
                <label for="page_options_custom_metabox">
                    <?php _e( 'Full Width', 'page_options' );?>
                </label>
                <input onclick="cbclick(event)"
                class="colcheck"
                    type="checkbox"
                    data="12"
                    id="page_options_custom_metabox_location_full"
                    name="page_options_custom_metabox[location_full]"
                    value="12"
                    <?php
                        checked( $details['location_full'], '12' );
                    ?>>
                <!--2 col-->
                <label for="page_options_custom_metabox">
                    <?php _e( '2 columns', 'page_options' );?>
                </label>
                <input onclick="cbclick(event)"
                class="colcheck"
                    type="checkbox"
                    data="6"
                    id="page_options_custom_metabox_location_2"
                    name="page_options_custom_metabox[location_2]"
                    value="6"
                    <?php
                        checked( $details['location_2'], '6' );
                    ?>>

                <!--3 col-->
                <label for="page_options_custom_metabox">
                    <?php _e( '3 columns', 'page_options' );?>
                </label>
                <input onclick="cbclick(event)"
                class="colcheck"
                    type="checkbox"
                    data="4"
                    id="page_options_custom_metabox_location_4"
                    name="page_options_custom_metabox[location_4]"
                    value="3"
                    <?php
                        checked( $details['location_4'], '3' );
                    ?>>
            <br>

            </div>
        </fieldset>
    <?php
    // Security field
    // This validates that submission came from the
    // actual dashboard and not the front end or
    // a remote server.
    wp_nonce_field( 'page_options_form_metabox_nonce', 'page_options_form_metabox_process' );
}


// Save the metabox
function page_options_save_metabox( $post_id, $post ) {
    // Verify that our security field exists. If not, bail.
    if ( !isset( $_POST['page_options_form_metabox_process'] ) ) return;
    // Verify data came from edit/dashboard screen
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['page_options_form_metabox_process'], 'page_options_form_metabox_nonce' ) ) {
        return $post->ID;
    }
    // Verify user has permission to edit post
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID )) {
        return $post->ID;
    }
    // Check that our custom fields are being passed along
    // This is the `name` value array. We can grab all
    // of the fields and their values at once.
    if ( !isset( $_POST['page_options_custom_metabox'] ) ) {
        return $post->ID;
    }

    // Sanitize all data
    // Set up an empty array
    $sanitized = array();
    // Loop through each of our fields
    foreach ( $_POST['page_options_custom_metabox'] as $key => $detail ) {
        // Sanitize the data and push it to our new array
        // `wp_filter_post_kses` strips our dangerous server values
        // and allows through anything you can include a post.
        $sanitized[$key] = wp_filter_post_kses( $detail );
    }
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'page_options', $sanitized);
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'page_options_save_metabox', 1, 2 );
```

I thought it had something to do with adding a selected function to the options but that still didn't do anything. I've also tried rewriting the save function a few times but same result.

The purpose of this meta box is to style and filter a post type as an alternative to using a shortcode.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the selected option as selected. Similar to how you are using `checked()` on your checkboxes you can use `selected()` on your option elements of your select element.

You can modify your `category_list` function as follows:

```
function category_list( $tag, $taxonomy, $selected ){
    $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);

    foreach ( $tax_terms as $term_single ) {
            print( '<'.$tag.' value="'.$term_single->name.'" ' . selected( $term_single->name, $selected ) . '>'.$term_single->name.'</'.$tag.'>');        
    } 
}
```

Then when you call the function pass the saved value for the `$selected` parameter.

`<?php category_list( 'option', 'location-city', $details[city] ); ?>`